# Particle with constant momenta?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

> Consider a particle of mass $m$ subjected to the following potential,
>   $$
> \vec{A}=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{B}\times\vec{r})
> $$
>   Where the magnetic field $\vec{B}$ is constant.

Can someone prove that $\dot{p}_{i}=0$,  $\forall i$?

i.e Prove that

$$
\dot{\vec{p}}=0
$$

Comment: You'll need to show, $\dot{p}_i = -\frac{\partial \mathcal H}{\partial q_i} = 0$.

Comment: @JamalS Thank you. It is 0 because $\vec{v}$ only changes if it exists an $\vec{E}$, and here is 0. Also, $\vec{A}$ is constant due to $B$ is constant. My computations are the following.
$$
H=\frac{1}{2m}\left(\vec{p} -\frac{q}{2}(\vec{B}\times \vec{r}) \right)^{2} \hspace{30mm} (3)
$$

$$
\dot{p}_{j}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_{j}}=-\frac{1}{m}(\vec{p}-\frac{q}{2} (\vec{B}\times \vec{r}))\frac{\partial (\vec{p}-\frac{q}{2} (\vec{B}\times \vec{r}))}{\partial x_j}=+\frac{1}{m}(p_l-\frac{q}{2}\epsilon_{lmn}B_{m}x_{n})(\frac{q}{2}\epsilon_{lmj}B_{m}) \hspace{10mm}(4)
$$
What is wrong?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform okay, sorry. But, is really $\dot{p}_{j}=0$ for $j=1,2,3$? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The momenta are NOT constant.  In the simplest case where $\vec B$ is along $\hat z$ along, the motion will be helicoidal and the momenta in the plane perpendicular to $\vec B$ cannot be constants as this would imply a straight trajectory.

Comment: Thank you. Are my computatioms right?    $$ H=\frac{1}{2m}\left(\vec{p} -\frac{q}{2}(\vec{B}\times \vec{r}) \right)^{2} $$ $$ \dot{p}_{j}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x_{j}}=-\frac{1}{m}(\vec{p}-\frac{q}{2} (\vec{B}\times \vec{r}))\frac{\partial (\vec{p}-\frac{q}{2} (\vec{B}\times \vec{r}))}{\partial x_j}=+\frac{1}{m}(p_l-\frac{q}{2}\epsilon_{lmn}B_{m}x_{n})(\frac{q}{2}\epsilon_{lmj}B_{m}) $$

Comment: I presume repeated indice are summed over.  There is probably a simpler final expression obtained by expanding the scalar product and using vector identities but I don't remember the details.

Comment: yes, repeated indice are summed over. If the expression I have obtained is correct, is enough for me. I have found in other source a different expression. Thank you